# Scrolling text view like a marquee in html

Tags: android, textview, marquee

Hi i need to add a continuously scrolling text view to my app.

I need to update the text from a website .

Can anyone tell me any tutorials where i can find the code to do it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text"
            android:textColor="#ff4500" />
```

In Activity :

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textId);
tv.setSelected(true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: but will it take the text from the web and also i want it to scroll continuously whether it is focused or not.

Comment: @user1844638 it will scroll continuously. You need to update text manually by fetching from web and update that text with this textview.

Comment: @user1844638 I just edited my solution with few required attributes to add. Otherwise it may not run on some device os or emulators.