# Application has stopped Unexpectedly due to NullPointerException

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to display the value of a string to a text View in java class. But when i run my app it is showing that my application has stopped unexpectedly. It is not working properly please suggest me a best way to do this.

My code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    currentPosition = position;
    playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), songs.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent in = new Intent(this, current_song.class);
    startActivity(in);

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "End of Song List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final String songName = songs.get(position).toString();
    final TextView textchange = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_song_name);
    textchange.setText(songName);

}
```

Layout xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/play_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play"
    />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/current_song_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Log:

```
01-26 22:29:16.599: I/Process(531): Sending signal. PID: 531 SIG: 9
01-26 22:29:28.679: D/AndroidRuntime(602): Shutting down VM
01-26 22:29:28.679: W/dalvikvm(602): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at    com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:71)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-26 22:29:28.750: E/AndroidRuntime(602):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It'd be nice to see the entire contents of  `com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.onListItemClick` including which line is number 71

Comment: line no 71 is textchange.setText(songName);

Comment: @Anu0042 can you please show which xml file used for `current_song.java` activity?

Comment: @Anu0042 see my edited answer for the full example to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do this from your list activity,

```
final TextView textchange = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_song_name);
textchange.setText(songName);
```

But this view is declared in the xml which you are using in `current_song.java` Activity.

You can't use view objects of one activity to other.

Pass the value of `songName` with bundle extras to `current_song` activity with intent and then set that `songName` in your `current_song` activity.

**From your List activity :**

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    currentPosition = position;
    final String songName = songs.get(position).toString();
    playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
    Intent in = new Intent(this, current_song.class);
    in.putExtra("song_name",songName );
    startActivity(in);
}
```

**In your current_song activity :**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
    String songName = extras.getString("song_name");
    TextView textchange = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_song_name);
    textchange.setText(songName);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot that was great. 1 more help can you tell me how to move this text like marque in html. I am asking this kind of silly question bec i am totally new to Android. please help me.

Comment: @Anu0042 see this link for marquee like text [ http://stackoverflow.com/a/14067328/556975 ].

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, if those three lines are in `onListItemClick()`, try:

```
final TextView textchange = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.current_song_name);
// Scope findVIewById to the the View ^^^
```

(If this isn't the answer, please indicate which line is 71.)

Comment: line no 71 is textchange.setText(songName);

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Also you may need to do this before calling `startActivity()`.

Comment: yes but is not working i am not getting the error but the page is not xml page do not contain song name

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand what you said... Are you trying to display the song name in your `current_song` Activity?

Comment: You cannot access the layout of another Activity. You must [pass the song name to `current_song`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2091465/1267661), the easiest way is to use a Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this too :

```
final String songName = songs.get(position).toString();
```

and make sure about the "position"